# Get parameters of object in metaclass of this object

Tags: python, django, scope, metaclass

My problem is a python/django mix. I have a form model that will display some fields. Basing on some parameter of this model, the data sent to metaclass creating this object should differ. But how can I reach this parameter when inside the body of Meta ? Should I use some global var instead of object parameter (as it is introduced only to store value temporarily) ?

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        instance = kwargs.get("instance")
        self.type = None
        try:
            type = self.instance.template_id
        except:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = ContentBase
        fields = ["title", "slug", "description", "text", "price",]

        #here I need to have the value of 'type'
        if type != 2:
            try:
                fields.remove("price")
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything dynamic within Meta. That's not what it's for.

Why can't you do it all within `__init__`? You can modify `self.fields` from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Daniel proposed, I moved the whole thing to `__init__` :

```
    type = None
    try:
        type = self.instance.template_id
    except:
        pass

    if type != 2:
        self.fields.pop("price")
    else:
```